# How do blocks signal whether it supports segwit for the 95% threshold?

Tags: blockchain, block, segregated-witness, activation-mechanism, bip9-version-bits

Ideally, I'd also like to see graphs that indicate how close we are to segwit adoption and the number of minimum blocks we are away from actual segwit adoption.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[BIP141 – Deployment](https://github.com/bitcoin/bips/blob/master/bip-0141.mediawiki#Deployment) says:

> This BIP will be deployed by "version bits" BIP9 with the name "segwit" and using bit 1.
>
> For Bitcoin mainnet, the BIP9 `starttime` will be midnight 15 november 2016 UTC (Epoch timestamp 1479168000) and BIP9 timeout will be midnight 15 november 2017 UTC (Epoch timestamp 1510704000).

As we're currently on the second version of blocks, the version field will be showing `0x20000002` when signaling readiness for segwit and `0x20000000` when not. Readiness for segwit2x would show as `0x20000010` if only signaling bit 4 or `0x20000012` if signaling both bit 1 and bit 4.

BIP 9 requires 95% readiness signaled over one difficulty period (from reset to reset). Once that is achieved, SegWit will be activated on the network after the following difficulty period has passed.

It appears that [Coin.Dance](https://coin.dance/blocks/proposals) will show support in the linked graph, as indicated by the footnote "BIP 141 (voting starts on 2016-11-15)".

*Note: In BIP9 signaling readiness only starts with the first difficulty retarget after the `starttime`. In the case of SegWit this is likely to be around the 19th of November.*

Comment: I assume (since I do not see it yet), that the black BIP 141 line will only be visible after the next retarget?

Comment: @JanusTroelsen: Signaling only starts after the retarget, so before then the line will be at 0%. I don't have any information on what coin.dance will do regarding the line. :)

Comment: So the version would be 0x20000002 if showing support and 0x20000000 if not?

Comment: @Alberts: I've updated my answer.